# Probem installing two prestashop 1.7 stores on the same domain

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a premlem i want to install 2 prestashop 1.7 stores but on the same domain 
the problem is i want to copy the old store on the new one and my urls of the store will be like this

```
mystore.com/myoldstore
mystore.com/mynewstore
```

what i did is i copied the old folder in the new one and also the database and i change the database configuration

but when i go to my new store

```
mystore.com/mynewstore
```

it keep redirecting me to the old store 
    mystore.com/myoldstore

i tried to modify the

```
PS_SHOP_DOMAIN and PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SLL
```

but the same problem keep redirecting me

Answer (score 0):

Why copy anything?

You should use the multi store feature of Prestashop which allows you to set multiple shops using the same domain and subdirectory.
They'll share the same admin interface, catalog but can have different themes, customers, modules enabled, content etc.

Check here for example, https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-create-a-new-shop-in-prestashop-1-7.html

EDIT: In this case you need to modify the configuration and shop_url tables in your DB.

Use phpMyAdmin or similar, go to your configuration table, find the PS_SHOP_DOMAIN and the PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL keys, check if the domain is the right one (the root domain, without the directories, e.g. example.com).

If corect, go to the shop_url table check if the domain is identical with the one from the configuration table and change the physical_uri record to your subdirectory (e.g. /my_subdirectory/)

Also check if in the .htaccess file if the Domain name is the correct one and change the following line

`RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]`
to

`RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/your_subdirectory/]`

These for each of your subdomains in their respective databases.

Comment: no i want two admins and two independent stores cuz i want to make one for testing and the other is the production

Answer (score 0):

Such an issue occurs when .htaccess is not correctly set. Check this file for the second store.

In 1.7, it comes with some default rewrite rules. For example:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DomainNameForStore1$
```

Replace it in the second store with appropriate domain string.

Sometimes the HTTP server needs to be restarted after such operations.

Hope it helps.